# Share the border between two UsersControls

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I've an ItemControl, which display a list of ContentControl in a StackPanel.

Inside this contentControl, I've a `Border`, which has BorderBrush that is conditionnally set.

My simplified case would be:

```
<ItemsControl ItemSource="{Binding SomeChildViewModels}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ConventionBasedDataTemplateSelector}"  />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Then the component that get loaded:

```
<UserControl 
<!-- ... All UC declarations -->
>

<Border>
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">

            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsHighlighted}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
    <!-- Rest of the control -->
</Border>

</UserControl>
```

The issue is that I've 2 pixels between each control, which actually look quite weird. And 2 pixels is useless because only one element can be highlighted.

I tried different things:

- Setting the BorderThickness to 0 and only to 1 when highlighted --> Everything jumps
- Setting a Partial BorderThickness, but this display only 3 elements

Is there a way to share this BorderThickness accross the borders?

Comment: Move the setter that sets the `BorderThickness` to`1` inside the `DataTrigger`? Or please clarify your issue.

Comment: @mm8 I tried but setting the borderThickness to 1 in the DataTrigger will result with everything being shifted when highlighted, I don't want the element to move when the DataTrigger kicks in